# Excel chart doesn't show 'value' on hover

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a combination chart on Excel 2013. It has both lines and stacked areas. When I hover over the lines, it shows all relevant information ('series', 'point' and 'value') of the data point.

[image: Over line]

When I hover over the areas, it shows only 'series' and 'point'.

[image: Over area]

I've done some research, but [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/identification-of-points-on-charts-when-mouse/8b06e27b-5c9b-4b69-a56c-012292db7395) doesn't seem to apply, the File > Options > Advanced > Chart > Show Data Point Values on Hover is checked. Besides, I wouldn't see anything on hover if it weren't.

Any idea how to display the value on hover?

Comment: @pnuts, no I haven't asked there.

Comment: @pnuts, doesn't seem to be any question there.

Comment: This is unfortunately all you get from an area chart.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as Jon Peltier mentioned above, the area chart does not show the y-axis value.  I  switched to 'Line chart' and 'Area Line chart' (on excel 16.x on OSX) and both showed the corresponding value off the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

Throw that same field twice in your pivot and go to Design / Change Chart Type / Combo. Keep your first field as a line chart and make the chart type for the second field (which is duplicate) "Area". Now, go to your chart and select the line curve and make it invisible.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. When I have time, I'll check it out. Thanks!